# GtkScrolledWindow + WebkitWebView Scrolling

Tags: c, webkit, gtk

Hey I am trying to make a GTK IRC client that uses webkit to display its messages.

The webview is within a ScrolledWindow, and I want the scrolledwindow to scroll to the bottom everytime it gets too big.

I've tried changing the vadjustment value of the scrolledwindow when a message is added but this doesn't seem to work at all. It keeps reseting it to 0 for some reason.

Does anyone know how I might solve this?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem. I believe the issue is caused because the `adjustment-changed` and `adjustment-value-changed` signals not always sent after the window has completely finished redrawing. This causes the adjustment value to be zero because the page has no content at that point. The solution is to connect to the [size-allocate](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkwidget.html#signal-gtkwidget--size-allocate) signal instead. This is only called when the window has completely finished resizing, and has the extra advantage of not being called when the user scrolls the window manually.

Here is a sample using python bindings:

```
def autoscroll_view(view, allocation):
    #parent is the gtk.ScrolledWindow that needs updating
    parent = view.get_parent()
    adj = parent.get_vadjustment()
    adj.value = adj.upper - adj.page_size
    parent.set_vadjustment(adj)


view = webkit.WebView()

window = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
window.add(view)

view.connect('size-allocate', autoscroll_view)
```

Comment: The typo should be fixed now. Glad I could help!